# Variable importance for random forests using caret

Tags: r, random-forest, caret, importance

Consider the following toy example dataset (in R), including 5 factors:

```r
set.seed(2022)
dat <- data.frame(
    V1 = factor(sample(0:1, 20, replace = TRUE)),
    V2 = factor(sample(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 20, replace = TRUE)),
    V3 = factor(sample(0:1, 20, replace = TRUE)),
    V4 = factor(sample(0:1, 20, replace = TRUE)),
    Y = factor(sample(0:1, 20, replace = TRUE))
)
summary(dat)
```

Let's build a random forest using the `caret` R package, to predict the variable `Y` against all other variables:

```r
library(caret)
rfcaret <- train(
    Y ~ .,
    data = dat,
    method = "rf"
)
varImp(rfcaret)
```

We get the following importance scores:

```
    Overall
V31  100.00
V11   83.69
V41   70.49
V2c   54.81
V2d   54.27
V2b    0.00
```

Here we get an importance score for all *factor levels*, instead of importance scores for all *factors*, as it is the case using the `randomForest` R package:

```r
library(randomForest)
forest <- randomForest(Y ~ ., data = dat)
importance(forest)
```

```
   MeanDecreaseGini
V1         1.271775
V2         3.100692
V3         1.221858
V4         1.212846
```

Here we have (as expected) an importance score *per variable*.

The help pages from `caret` do not document very clearly this behavior, and furthermore, they say that `caret::varImp()` is only a wrapper for `randomForest::importance()`, which is clearly not true (as noted [in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39880068/11238320)).

So, what are the importance scores from caret? And theoretically, what is an importance score for a factor *level*? (It basically seems that caret transforms each factor into a series of dummy/binary factors... which I could not find in the docs, and which is not really what I want here.)

Have you any clue about this behavior, and the rationale of this behavior?

Thanks!